# Using PDFsharp in Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, pdfsharp

I have an issue with using PDFsharp and MigraDoc with `Xamarin.ios`. The reason is because `System.Drawing` isn't available in `Xamarin.ios`. I am not actually sure how I can edit the sample code from PDFsharp to work with Ios. Hopefully somebody can help.

This is the sample code used from the PDFsharp website and getting an error at `gfx.DrawString`:

```
static void CreatePdf()
    {
        // Create a new PDF document
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

        // Create an empty page
        PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

        // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

        // Create a font
        XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

        // Draw the text !ERROR IS HERE!
        gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
          new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
          XStringFormats.Center);

        // Save the document...
        const string filename = "HelloWorld.pdf";
        document.Save(filename);
        // ...and start a viewer.
        Process.Start(filename);
    }
```

[Image Showing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylyzC.png)

Comment: `gfx.DrawString` is a method from PDFsharp. Which error message do you get? Did you add the `using` statements for PDFsharp?

Comment: @Viveladéraison Yes I have added all the using statements. However, I haven't actually ran the code because I get the red line under this part of the code. When I right click it says I need to add reference to System.Drawing. However, this is not available in Xamarin.ios.

Comment: Add System, System.core, System.xml in references.  Also add "using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;"  this should solve your issue.

Comment: @Darshana I have tried adding all them namespaces but still no success. I have appended a screenshot to my main question which shows the error I get and the resolution visual studio gives me